# Actionbar/toolbar background color is not changing at all xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

### hello i have project that use multiple activity and xml one of this xml is navigation drawer it's easy to change backgournd color of actionbar/toolbar but when i change it on the other layout/xml background actionbar/tooolbar not change how to change all of them it's

Screenshot
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXVCr.png)

on this change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ir.diamonddesign.tajrobi96.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

on this not change

```
/*
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ir.diamonddesign.tajrobi96.Questionsactivity"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAppe``arance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/kharej_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/dakhel_text"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:textDirection="rtl" />

</RelativeLayout>*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the file named styles.xml in your res folder.
You should have defined a theme for your project which looks something like below code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/text_description</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_teal</item>
</style>
```

Here, colorPrimary defines the color of your actionBar. This color must have been set to blue acc to the screenshot.
Try changing the colorPrimary value to the desired color that you want.

Comment: i agreed with abhinav.

Answer (score 0):

Change style.xml:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

to :

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
```